# html5 <audio>: Volume animation choppy in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, animation, html5-audio

I'm working on a script that plays a certain html5 `<audio>` element whenever a certain `<div>` is hovered over. I'm using jQuery to detect the hover, and to fade in/out the audio by animating the volume.

Here's my code:

```
<head>
<!--  unrelated code removed -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //unrelated code removed
    $("#pog").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#poga").get(0).volume=0;
        $("#poga").get(0).play();
        $("#poga").animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
    });
    $("#pog").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#poga").animate({volume: 0}, 1000, function() {
            $("#poga").get(0).pause();
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio preload loop controls id="poga">
        <source src="audio/phantogram.mp3"></source>
        <source src="audio/phantogram.ogg"></source>
        Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
    </audio>
    <div id="pog" class="band">Phantogram</div>
</body>
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2eG6s/

The problem is that the volume animation is really choppy. It fades in and fades out in intervals (I don't know the exact volumes, but something like 100%, 60%, 20%). It's really weird, and only happens in Firefox 21.0 and 22.0 for Windows 7 (the Mac versions of Firefox 21.0 and 22.0 work fine.)

**Help!**

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was fixed quite some time ago: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=487504

The problem was the audio buffer and how the old `libsydneyaudio` backend could work with it. The buffer was not purged on volume changed, so the audible change only occoured after the currently buffered audio had finished playing.

Somehow the new `cubeb` backend, which according to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=852401 is up and running, should have fixed this, but apparently there are still problems, and to me this still sounds like a buffering issue.

I've used to use a workaround that invoked the `play()` method in the `volumechange` event, that helped to make it less choppy, but now there seems to be no difference when doing this.

So while I don't have a solution (if there is one at all) for this problem, I thought this information might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I'll wait and see if anyone has figured out a solution. Stupid bugs! :P